# Using gson to deserialize specific JSON field of an object

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have the following JSON string:

```
{
    "ms": "images,5160.1",
    "turl": "http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=I4693880201938488&pid=1.1",
    "height": "178",
    "width": "300",
    "imgurl": "http://www.attackingsoccer.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/World-Cup-2012-Draw.jpg",
    "offset": "0",
    "t": "World Cup 2014 Qualification – Europe Draw World Cup 2012 Draw ...",
    "w": "719",
    "h": "427",
    "ff": "jpeg",
    "fs": "52",
    "durl": "www.attackingsoccer.com/2011/07/world-cup-2012-qualification-europe...",
    "surl": "http://www.attackingsoccer.com/2011/07/world-cup-2012-qualification-europe-draw/world-cup-2012-draw/",
    "mid": "D9E91A0BA6F9E4C65C82452E2A5604BAC8744F1B",
    "k": "6",
    "ns": "API.images"
}
```

I need to store the value of `imgurl` in a separate string.

This is what I have till now, but this just gives me the whole JSON string instead of the specific imgurl field.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = new Data();
data = gson.fromJson(toExtract, Data.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

`toExtract` is the JSON string. 
Here is my data class:

```
public class Data 
{
    public List<urlString> myurls;
}

class urlString
{
    String imgurl;
}
```

Comment: See also [Get nested JSON object with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit) which better answers question's title.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When parsing such a simple structure, no need to have dedicated classes.

**Solution 1 :**

To get the imgurURL from your String with gson, you can do this :

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(toExtract).getAsJsonObject();
String imgurl = obj.get("imgurl").getAsString();
```

This uses a raw parsing into a [JsonObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html).

**Solution 2 :**

Alternatively, you could extract your whole data in a `Properties` instance using

```
 Properties data = gson.fromJson(toExtract, Properties.class);
```

and read your URL with

```
String imgurl = data.getProperty("imgurl");
```

Comment: Thank You! This really helped! Could you also please explain to me why my code didn't work? I saw a few other examples where making dedicated classes also worked.

Comment: That's because the json structure doesn't correspond to an object containing a list of strings. It would have been like `{["a", "anotherurl","ttt"]}`.

Comment: Instead of toString() it is better to use getAsString() otherwise it will contain extra quotes.

Comment: @TomášLinhart [You're perfectly right](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java#319), I fix that

Comment: Thanks! The second solution does not work for me, but the first one does it perfect !

Comment: This solution uses Google Gson library. For those that are using Jackson library, the solution is:

final String json = "{\"contentType\": \"foo\", \"fooField1\": ... }";
final ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, ObjectNode.class);

if (node.has("contentType")) {
    System.out.println("contentType: " + node.get("contentType"));
}

Refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190851/get-single-field-from-json-using-jackson

Comment: As @AlirezaFattahi said, the second solution did not worked for me either.