# Does Retrofit support keypath on json parsing or something alike?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

For example i have json looks like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "name": "two"
        }
    ]
}
```

For example i have object User with field name.

Is it possible write method which will parse data array to objects User?

something like

```
Call<List<User>> getUsers(@KeyPath("data"))
```

Now to do this, i need create a wrapper class something like

```
public class UsersWrapper {
    @SerializeName("data")
    public ArrayList<User> users;
}
```

and in service i do next

```
public interface Service {
    @GET("users")
    Call<UsersWrapper> getUsers()
}
```

But my all requests is just response with data but variable objects in array.

In this case i need create wrappers to any data requests. Pain :(

?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your response object should be an array of `User`

Comment: I tend to solve that by making the call return a `JsonObject`, then chain the call in a transformer that uses a gson instance to get the list from the `JsonObject`. And then I go after the API writer until they change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

Global class `Wrapper<T>` to parse the whole JSON

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    public List<T> data;
}
```

And `User` to parse actual array;

```
public class User {
    public String name;
}
```

Then, the API interface:

```
@GET("/people")
Wrapper<User> getUsers();
```

And in `DataSource` class just do something like this:

```
@Override
public List<User> getUsers() {
    Wrapper<User> usersWrapper = myApiInterface.getUsers();
    return usersWrapper.data;
}
```

**Upd1:**
Another solution is to create custom `JsonDeserializer` (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit)) for `List<User>` type, register by `registerTypeAdapter` it with your custom `Gson` object and then you can deserialise your Json directly into `List<User>`. Though, this solution brings much more extra code and potential benefit is unclear for me.

Comment: That works. You can also generalize that for several API calls to `class Wrapper<T> { public List<T> data; }` provided that your responses all use the same `data` key.