# Parse a specific field of a JSON without a wrapper class

Tags: java, json, resttemplate, jackson-databind

Java object:

```
public class Foo {
 @JsonProperty("name")
 private String name;
 @JsonProperty("surname")
 private String surname;

 // getters + setters
}
```

JSON:

```
   {  
   "meta":{  
      "code":200
   },
   "data":[  
      {  
         "name":"John",
         "surname":"Smith"
      }
   ]
}
```

API call:

```
return restTemplate.getForEntity(requestUrl, Foo[].class).getBody();
```

Is it possible to parse "data" array without creating an additional wrapper class? I tried adding the `@JsonRootName("data")` annotation on top of my Java class, but it did not work.

Comment: Gson can do this fairly easily. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231894/using-gson-and-retrofit-2-to-deserialize-complex-api-responses

Comment: that looks even more complex - adding hundreds of classes for parsing is not what I am looking for

Comment: Hundreds? It's 1 TypeAdapterFactory and Jackson has custom deserialization itself. Java is object oriented, so what do you have against classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
String name = obj.getJSONObject("data").getString("name");
```

Comment: Looks like Jackson is used, not org.json