# Retrofit 2.0 parse dynamic json from same POJO class

Tags: android, retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo

**What I Have**

I have a server `success response`

```
{
  "response_code": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "message": "enqiry chat fetched successfully",
  "meta_data": {
    "count": "6"
  },
  "data": {
    "enquiries": [
    ]
  }
}
```

When `Error` , the same `API` returns

```
{
  "response_code": 500,
  "status": "error",
  "meta_data": {
    "count": 0
  },
  "data": [],
  "message": "Please specify all required parameter to add enquiries"
}
```

**What happened**

At `error scenario` the **data** is changed from **JsonObject** to **JsonArray**

**My Problem**

At success response everything works fine (because I made `POJO class` from `success response` )

At error response my app crashes saying **Tried to read object but found array**

**What I can't do**

I can't change the `back-end` , because it is already developed and works for website also .

**What I did**

I googled and found many solutions which I cannot relate to my issues

**POJO**

```
public class ReviewModel {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private Data mData;

    public Data getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public class Data {

        @SerializedName("reviews")
        private List<Review> mReviews;

        public List<Review> getReviews() {
            return mReviews;
        }

        public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
            mReviews = reviews;
        }

    }



    public class Review {

        @SerializedName("comment_date")
        private String mCommentDate;

        public String getCommentDate() {
            return mCommentDate;
        }

        public void setCommentDate(String comment_date) {
            mCommentDate = comment_date;
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: I suggest Instead of defining one type like JSONObject or JSONArray use Object ...

Comment: your `data` should be either `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`. In case it doesn't have any data you will get it blank.

Comment: Why dont you using gson library ?

Comment: Please, show your retrofit instance creation code. I am using different objects for error and normal flow and they work fine.

Comment: Please see my POJO class and suggest me the change

Comment: You could intercept the response and check the response code you get. This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37244522/3495069

Comment: @SerializedName("data")
    private Object mData; then try to convert in Arraylist or Pojo

Comment: @Pravin : let me change this

Comment: @Pravin : I did , but where do I check whether it it object or array . Normally I read my pojo getter method at onNext() of RxJava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use some thing like this ,

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Response {

    @SerializedName("response_code")
    @Expose
    private Integer responseCode;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("meta_data")
    @Expose
    private MetaData metaData;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> data = null;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public Integer getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void setResponseCode(Integer responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public MetaData getMetaData() {
        return metaData;
    }

    public void setMetaData(MetaData metaData) {
        this.metaData = metaData;
    }

    public List<Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Object> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    public class MetaData {

        @SerializedName("count")
        @Expose
        private Integer count;

        public Integer getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(Integer count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

    }
 }
```

And use a Custom Array Adapter with Gson,

ArrayAdapter class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = null;
        try {
            if (type.getRawType() == List.class || type.getRawType() == ArrayList.class) {

                typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(gson,
                        (Class) ((ParameterizedType) type.getType())
                                .getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return typeAdapter;

    }

}
```

ArrayAdapterFactory class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class ArrayAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<List<T>> {

    private Class<T> adapterclass;
    private Gson gson;

    public ArrayAdapter(Gson gson, Class<T> adapterclass) {
        this.adapterclass = adapterclass;
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        final JsonToken token = reader.peek();
        System.out.println(token);
        // Handling of Scenario 2( Check JavaDoc for the class) :
        if (token == JsonToken.STRING || token == JsonToken.NUMBER ||
                token == JsonToken.BOOLEAN) {
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            // Handling of Scenario 1(Check JavaDoc for the class) :
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
                list.add(inning);
            }
            reader.endArray();
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, List<T> value) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

And register the adapter factory like this,

```
Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
```

This will help to deserialise the json string.

Comment: I have doubt . Is this the elegant way Or a work around ?

Comment: It is elegant way , if you dont want to change in the backend side.