# GSON if deserialized string contains another JSON

Tags: android, json, gson

Not so typical situation.
I have next JSON string from server:
`{"SomeElements":[{"Id":"Title","Info":"{\"Text\": \"Sometext\"}"}]}`

Here is graphic representation of it:

[image]

The problem is that string `Info` contains another `JSON` string.
Here is my POJO:

```
public class Test {
    private ArrayList<SomeElement> SomeElements;

    public class SomeElement {
        private String Id;
        private String Info;
    }
}
```

**Question** - is there some way to parse `Info` string not as String, but as HashMap (for example) in my POJO?
If I try to declare it as `HashMap<String, String>`, I have an error `"Expected OBJECT, but was STRING"`.

***What is the best approach to handle this issue? Custom deserializer is the only way?***

**!!** This question is NOT a duplicate !!
I cannot change JSON response from the server.
Please read carefully - I'm asking, is it possible to parse `Info` string not as string, but as another JSON.

**SOLUTION** I ended up with next.
I declared `private LinkedTreeMap<String, String> infoMap;` and Firstly deserialize `Info` as String. Then:

```
public LinkedTreeMap<String, String> getInfoMap() {
            if (infoMap == null) {
                infoMap = new Gson().fromJson(info, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());
            }
            return infoMap;
        }
```

I suppose this is much easier than writing custom deserializer, but maybe in more complex cases custom deserializer would be an only option.
So in general case answer of @arjabbar would work better.

Comment: For what reason you want to do it?

Comment: Simple - I want to parse response from server side into a usable class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but I think your best bet is to just make a custom Deserializer. It's not your only way, but once you get used to writing Deserializers, it's not so bad.

[Here are some decent examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose custom Deserializer would be the only option. Main problem that Info is a String - if it would be nested JSON, that's would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here Info is also object. so you need to create the class for info.

```
public class Test {
    private ArrayList<SomeElement> SomeElements;

    public class SomeElement {
        private String Id;
        private Info info;
    }

}
class Info{
private String text;
private String sometext;
//getter and setter 
}
```

Comment: It's not working, as Info is a String: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 46`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class for the `Info` object as well so that `GSON` will deserialize it for you.

Try this:

```
public class EntireJsonObject {
    private ArrayList<SomeElement> someElements;
}

public class SomeElement {
    private String id;
    private Info info;
}

public class Info {
    private String text;
}
```

You need to have `GSON` deserialize the `JSON` response from the server to a `EntireJsonObject`. `GSON` will handle all the inner conversions and deserializations for you. Now you can access the "SomeText" as through a getter from the `Info` object.

It is important to note that your variable names **do not** have to exactly match the keys returned in the `JSON` response. `GSON` will translate variable names based on various schemes (camelCase, under_scores, and many more). You can specify the conversion protocal `GSON` uses when you create the object.

If you absolutely want the `Info` as a `HashMap<String, String>`, you will have to write the deserializer for that individually. I would check the `GSON` docs, as you may not have to write a custom deserializer for the entire `JSON` response, but rather just the inner object.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working - reason is the same - Info is a String: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 46`

Comment: @GoltsevEugene Ah, I see. I did not notice that the entire field was encapsulated in quotes. In that case, you will have to use a custom deserializer as arjabbar mentioned above