# Retrofit2 Specify root element and convert datatype

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I've just started working with Retrofit2 and the API I'm consuming wraps all valid responses in a "response" object as shown below. I need to tell Retrofit to parse only the values within response without actually nesting them inside another object. For the login code, I'm also faced with the issue of getting a String which I want to convert to an actual time stamp.

This is a sample response from a login request:

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "response":{  
      "token":"test_token",
      "expires":"1485217863"
   }
}
```

In the above the only two actual values are:

```
token
expires
```

I'm hoping to end up with something like what is shown below.

```
public class Token {

  @SerializedName("token")
  String token;

  @SerializedName("expires")
  Timestamp expires;

  public User(String token, String expires ) {
    this.token
    this.expires = //conversion code omitted. 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. You can either use a custom serialiser/deserialiser, type adapters, or you can simply use pojos and unwrap the result yourself.

Let me start with the easiest solution I can think of. Picture you have these classes:

```
public class ResponseData<T> {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    String status;
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    T response;

    public T getResponse() {
      return response;
    }
    // getters and setters and friends
}

public class Token {
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    String token;

    @SerializedName("expires")
    @Expose
    Timestamp expires;

    public Token(String token, String expires) {
        this.token = token;
        this.expires = expires;
    }
}
```

So one first thing to notice is the use of `@Expose`. This is a nice to have, but not extremely necessary. It helps you out when you have custom serialisers.

I assumed that you can have multiple api endpoints that return the same kind of body, where the json is:

```
{  
 "status":"success",
 "response":{  
  // Can be anything
 }
}
```

And as you can see the response can be anything.

You can then make your retrofit calls return `ResponseData<Token>` and in your callbacks you can check the value of `status` and see if you can do `getResponse` to unpack the result. The advantage of this approach is that you can reuse `ResponseData` fairly easily.

Another approach is to use custom serialisers or type adapters. This is in my opinion more laborious, but still a valid approach. I think the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit) here is quite extensive and explains how you can do this to get the nested object inside `response`.

To prepare retrofit to use the type adapters, you'll need to inject a configured `Gson` instance into it. Here's how:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Token.class, new YourTypeAdapter())
    .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
   // ....
```

As you can see, we pass the created gson with your type adapter to the `GsonConverterFactory` used by retrofit. This prepares retrofit to serialise and deserialise `Token` objects using the given type adapter.

I think the main disadvantage with this approach is that if you want to write a generic deserialiser/serialiser/typeadapter it can become complicated quite fast (assuming you won't have only a `Token` object).