# Parse a huge JSON object which has arrays and object in it using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a below JSON document in which `items` is an array which will contain multiple `item` objects. And each `item` object has many fields as shown below. For simplicity purpose, I am showing only one `item` object in an `items` array but it can have more.

```
{
    "items": [{
            "createDate": 1234567890,
            "title": "some title",
            "bp": {
                "currencyId": "USD",
                "value": 10.0
            },
            "pof": false,
            "ku": true,
            "var": {
                "quant": 10,
                "tot": 0,
                "co": 1,
                "vbp": {
                    "cid": "USD",
                    "val": 10.0
                },
                "id": 5296164,
                "sel": {
                    "style": "Short",
                    "Size": "L",
                    "Color": "Blue"
                }
            },
            "flags": {
                "low": false,
                "rpl": false,
                "scmb": false
            }
            "shipping": {
                "shippingType": "sss"
            },
            "seller": {
                "name": "",
                "sco": 0,
                "perc": 0.0,
                "id": 101215,
                "brand": true,
                "prog": "NONE"
            },
            "dur": "DA9",
            "urls": ["world", "hello"],
            "itemId": 1234
        }
    ],
    "count": {
        "ac": 3,
        "ed": 0
    }
}
```

How can I parse my above JSON into a POJO using Gson? I am confused because it has lot of JSON object fields in it so not able to understand how to make a class which can hold all those things.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use JSONschema2Pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#the-command-line-interface)

example usage:

```
jsonschema2pojo --source ../Items.json --target java-gen -a GSON -T JSON -E
```

output:

```
Bp.java  Count.java  Flags.java  Item.java  Sel.java  Seller.java  Shipping.java  Items.java  Var.java  Vbp.java
```

Seller.java

```
public class Seller {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("sco")
    @Expose
    private Integer sco;
    @SerializedName("perc")
    @Expose
    private Double perc;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    @Expose
    private Boolean brand;
    @SerializedName("prog")
    @Expose
    private String prog;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getSco() {
        return sco;
    }

    public void setSco(Integer sco) {
        this.sco = sco;
    }

    public Double getPerc() {
        return perc;
    }

    public void setPerc(Double perc) {
        this.perc = perc;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(Boolean brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getProg() {
        return prog;
    }

    public void setProg(String prog) {
        this.prog = prog;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

}
```

Put all of those classes into a package.

```
items
```

Then you can deserialize

```
String line = "{}" // Read JSON in.
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Items items = gson.fromJson(line, Items.class);
```

Comment: My `items` is an array which will contain multiple item object? will this still work?

Comment: Yeah you should feed in your entire schema/object to this tool though.