# Parsing a simple one line json in Java

Tags: java, gson

I'm actually trying to parse the game time from this page https://api.mikx.ca/7d2d/mx7d-hard.json
So far I only get the whole line everything i've tried to get the "days" is not working

```
InputStream sevenDays = null;

    sevenDays = new URL("https://api.mikx.ca/7d2d/mx7d-hard.json").openStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sevenDays, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1)
    {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
   JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
   jsonParser.parse(sb.toString());
   JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
   Object object = jsonParser.parse(sb.toString());
   json = (JsonObject) object;
```

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit) may help you

Comment: Thank you ! I thought i had searched , look like I was wrong