# GET request using Retrofit 2 in android studio does not seem to be working despite query parameters being correct

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

I'm using Retrofit 2 in Android Studio to get stop information in 
JSON form from the CUMTD api for stops and for some reason I get this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference, despite my GET request and query parameters being okay.

My MTD api interface:

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

/**
 * Class that details the request(s) that we will call
 */

public interface MTDApi{
    @GET("GetStops")
    Call<List<UserModel>> loadStops(
            @Query("api_key") String key,
            @Query("stop name") String stop
    );

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://developer.cumtd.com/api/v2.2/json/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}
```

My UserModel class:

```
public class UserModel {
    String stop_id;
    public String getStop_id(){
        return stop_id;
    }
    public void setStop_id(String stop_id){
        this.stop_id = stop_id;
    }
}
```

My main activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static android.R.attr.x;
import static android.media.CamcorderProfile.get;
import static com.example.neelpatel.weatherapp.MTDApi.retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String key= "<APIKEY>";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//Starts Retrofit
        final MTDApi mtdApi = MTDApi.retrofit.create(MTDApi.class);

        //Sets up Button and EditText for use in this class
        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        Button requestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //Behavior once button is clicked
        requestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String s = edit.getText().toString();
                //Sets up up the API call
                Call<List<UserModel>> call = mtdApi.loadStops(key,s);

                //Runs the call on a different thread
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    //Once the call has finished

                public void onResponse(Call<List<UserModel>> call, Response<List<UserModel>> response) {
                    //Gets the list of stops
                    List<UserModel> stops = response.body();
                    String text = stops.get(0).getStop_id();
                    edit.setText(text);
                }

                    @Override
                    //If the call failed
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<UserModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                        edit.setText("Request Failed");
                        Log.e("RequestCall", "Request failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.neelpatel.weatherapp.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="133dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Request"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add the stack trace to your question, not just the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In onResponse you should check that response.isSuccessful() and check that stops != null. It seems that your server returns error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should *always* check whether the response was successful (i.e. it's in the range of [200, 300) of HTTP status codes). You can do this in your `onResponse(...)` method:

```
 public void onResponse(Call<List<UserModel>> call, Response<List<UserModel>> response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
           //Gets the list of stops
           List<UserModel> stops = response.body();
           String text = stops.get(0).getStop_id();
           edit.setText(text);
      } else {
           // show error message
      }
 }
```

Also, your query is wrong. According to the documentation of [`GetStops`](https://developer.cumtd.com/documentation/v2.2/method/GetStops), it expects a `key` query parameter, not an `api_key` one (and also you're passing a `stop name` one which has a space in it). So your URL (in the end) will (should) look like `https://developer.cumtd.com/api/v2.2/json/GetStops?key=<your_api_key>`. This means that your endpoint description in the interface should look like this:

```
@GET("GetStops")
Call<List<UserModel>> loadStops(@Query("key") String key);
```

It's also worth mentioning that your expected response is not matching the actual response's structure which you can see in the [sample](https://developer.cumtd.com/documentation/v2.2/method/GetStops#sample). If you don't want to create that structure manually, you can use JSON to POJO converters, such as [this one](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) that you can use to, in fact, convert the sample into a proper POJO model structure.

Comment: But it says api key for the parameter so I can't just pass in the api key as a string for it?

Comment: I clarified this part in my answer. Also note that your expected model's structure is not matching the actual response's structure.

Comment: So i should add the key to the method in the main activity then when i call loadstops?

Comment: You do this right now by calling `mtdApi.loadStops(key, s);`. Only thing is that you don't need the `s` parameter anymore. But as I see you want to do some kind of a search. Shouldn't you use [GetStopsBySearch](https://developer.cumtd.com/documentation/v2.2/method/GetStopsBySearch) instead?

Comment: Yeah I changed it to getstopsbysearch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864916/issues-with-get-request-using-retrofit-in-android-studio this is the link to the new question for it, apparently I cannot connect now for some reason, would you mind taking a look at the code in this question?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.cumtd.com/documentation/v2.2/method/GetStops), the server return a **JSON Object** and not a **JSON Array**, as you seem to expect when you wrote the type `List<UserModel>` in your retrofit interface. The array you want is the `stops` field in the object, so you may want to either:

- create a *POJO* that matches the returned JSON Object and get the array from there
- create a custom Gson deserializer as explained in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23071080/1424030).