# Anyway to skip certain JSON sections

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to parse JSON using Retrofit and I am wondering if there is a way to skip or pass over the root object. Below is a snippet of the JSON.

```
{
"?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
},
"root": {
    "uri": {
        "#cdata-section": "http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns&json=y"
    },
    "stations": {
        "station": [
            {
                "name": "12th St. Oakland City Center",
                "abbr": "12TH",
                "gtfs_latitude": "37.803768",
                "gtfs_longitude": "-122.271450",
                "address": "1245 Broadway",
                "city": "Oakland",
                "county": "alameda",
                "state": "CA",
                "zipcode": "94612"
            },
            {
                "name": "West Oakland",
                "abbr": "WOAK",
                "gtfs_latitude": "37.804872",
                "gtfs_longitude": "-122.295140",
                "address": "1451 7th Street",
                "city": "Oakland",
                "county": "alameda",
                "state": "CA",
                "zipcode": "94607"
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": ""
  }
}
```

I have POJOs for root, stations, and station. I also have a StationList class that is listed below.

```
public class StationList {

  private int id;

  @SerializedName("root")
  @Expose
  private Root root;

  public int getId() {return id;}

  public Root getRoot() {
    return root;
  }
}
```

If I want to access the first station name ("12th St. Oakland City Center") I have to use this syntax

```
stationList.getRoot().getStations().getStation().get(0).getName()
```

Is there anyway It could be

```
stationList.getStation().get(0).getName();
```

I want to just ignore the root JSON object as I only want the list of stations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get nested JSON object with GSON using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit)

Comment: Why not implementing those methods in the pojos?

Answer (score 0):

add this method to your StationList class

```
public String getStationName(int i) {return getRoot().getStations().getStation().get(i).getName()}
```