# looping through nested json array is adding previously assigned value to data model

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-json

please look into this json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "Thursday 1, August, 2019",
      "time": [
        {
          "times": "1:13PM to 1:13PM",
          "notice": "testing",
          "category": "Meeting"
        },
        {
          "times": "12:00PM to 1:00PM",
          "notice": "Meeting",
          "category": "Meeting"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Friday 2, August, 2019",
      "time": [
        {
          "times": "3:00PM to 3:30PM",
          "notice": "Appointment",
          "category": "Meeting"
        },
        {
          "times": "12:00PM to 12:30PM",
          "notice": "Appointment",
          "category": "Meeting"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Monday 5, August, 2019",
      "time": [
        {
          "times": "11:00AM to 11:30AM",
          "notice": "Obj",
          "category": "Meeting"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm polulating this json data to my ArrayList like this:

```
VipPojo playerModel;
try {
    JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray dataArrays1 = dataobj.getJSONArray("time");
        String date = dataobj.getString("date");
        System.out.println("date: " + date); // here I get correct data (all 3 items);
        for (int j = 0; j < dataArrays1.length(); j++) {
            playerModel = new VipPojo();
            JSONObject dataobj1 = dataArrays1.getJSONObject(j);
            playerModel.setDate(date); // this is adding same previous assigned "date" until loop ends(I get 5 data with duplicate values)
            playerModel.setTimes(dataobj1.getString("times"));
            playerModel.setNotice(dataobj1.getString("notice"));
            playerModel.setCategory(dataobj1.getString("category"));
            dataModelArrayList.add(playerModel);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

as I mentioned in comments in code above, `"date"` object is adding previously assigned value to data model since `setDate()` is being used inside the inner loop which I don't want that.

Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

use Gson library [Get nested JSON object with GSON using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit)

for nested object use an object in itself

for more information  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-nested-objects

Answer (score 0):

Change
`playerModel.setDate(dataobj.getString("date"));`
to
`playerModel.setDate(date);`

Comment: I know. it should be `dataobj `. `"date"` object should be assigned with outer array as the json data shows.

Answer (score 0):

isn't "date" field static in VipPojo

Comment: what's the difference, model object is initializing in this loop anyway. yet I've tried that and it didn't worked.

Comment: I print dataModelArrayList:     for (VipPojo vp: dataModelArrayList) {
            Log.d("gggggg", vp.date);
        }

Comment: result: Thursday 1, August, 2019
Thursday 1, August, 2019
Friday 2, August, 2019
Friday 2, August, 2019
Monday 5, August, 2019

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
VipPojo playerModel;
try {
    JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
    playerModel = new VipPojo();
        JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray dataArrays1 = dataobj.getJSONArray("time");
        String date = dataobj.getString("date");
        System.out.println("date: " + date); // here I get correct data (all 3 items);
        playerModel.setDate(date);
        for (int j = 0; j < dataArrays1.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject dataobj1 = dataArrays1.getJSONObject(j);
             // this is adding same previous assigned "date" until loop ends(I get 5 data with duplicate values)
            playerModel.setTimes(dataobj1.getString("times"));
            playerModel.setNotice(dataobj1.getString("notice"));
            playerModel.setCategory(dataobj1.getString("category"));
            dataModelArrayList.add(playerModel);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```