# Parsing retrofit response into custom object containing custom object on Android

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, response

I have a problem with parsing my custom response because the I have a response with Localization properties.

I am recieving a response that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "dummyID1",
        "name.en_US": "dummyNameEn1",
        "name.fi_FI": "dummyNameFi1"
    },
    {
        "id": "dummyID2",
        "name.en_US": "dummyNameEn2",
        "name.fi_FI": "dummyNameFi2"
    },
    {
        "id": "dummyID3",
        "name.en_US": "dummyNameEn3",
        "name.fi_FI": "dummyNameFi3"
    }...
]
```

And to parse that I have created a custom class `Device.java`:

```
public class Device {

    public String id;
    public LocalizedString name;

    public Device(String id, LocalizedString name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Now here we have a custom object named `LocalizedString.java`:

```
public class LocalizedString implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<LocalizedString> CREATOR = new Creator<LocalizedString>() {
        @Override
        public LocalizedString createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new LocalizedString(in);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalizedString[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LocalizedString[size];
        }
    };

    private String en_US;
    private String fi_FI;

    public LocalizedString(String en, String fi) {
        this.en_US = en;
        this.fi_FI = fi;
    }

    protected LocalizedString(Parcel in) {
        en_US = in.readString();
        fi_FI = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(en_US);
        dest.writeString(fi_FI);
    }
//Getters, setters
}
```

Now in my response I want to create a list of `Device's` but it does not seem to understand how the ´LocalizedString´ works. Since my request is returning a `<List<Device>>` I cannot really customly parse it either.

Here is how I try to parse it:

```
        Call<List<Device>> call = getMainActivity().getRestClient().getDevices();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Device>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Device>> call, Response<List<Device>> response) {
                if (isAttached()) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        // get data
                       List<Device> items = response.body();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Device>> call, Throwable t) {
                if (isAttached()) {
                    Logger.debug(getClass().getName(), "Could not fetch installation document devices past orders", t);
                    getMainActivity().showError(R.string.error_network);
                }
            }
        });
```

And:

```
@GET("document/devices")
Call<List<Device>> gettDevices();
```

What am I supposed to do in this situation to bind the `name` to the `Device` and later be able to either get `en_US` or `fi_FI`.

Comment: You can replace `name.` to `empty` string before parsing, it will work fine then.

Comment: @Sunny Sorry, I tried to understand it but I could not. What did you mean by replacing `name.` with `empty`

Comment: I mean when you get json string in that string replace `"name.en_US"` to `en_US`

Comment: @Sunny So you mean manually go over the response and replace all of the `name.en_US` to `en_US` and then the same for the other language?

Comment: using `replaceAll("name.", "")` in response string and then parse

Comment: @Sunny I understand now what you mean but that will not work in my opinion since when doing the `Call` method, it is trying to manually parse the response beforehand and all that I am left with in my response is the `Response<List<Device>> response` which has all the ID's like it should but all the names are `null`. What I asssume should be done here is to teach the `Device` class to interpret the response because at the moment it does not understand what that means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better you can write it like this

```
public class Device {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("name.en_US")
    public String en;

    @SerializedName("name.fi_FI")
    public String fi;

    public Device(String id, String english, String fi) {
        this.id = id;
        this.en = english;
        this.fi = fi;
     }
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: It should be `String` instead of the `LocalizedString` in the constructor i assume?

Comment: And also adding `this.name = new LocalizedString(english, fi);` to the Constructor doesnt seem to work, but I do need the `LocalizedString`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @kataroty Sorry my bad.

Comment: If my guess is correct then it doesnt even go to the `constructor` to map the value to the `LocalizedString`. Any idea how to assign value to that?

Comment: yes It generally use a no-argument (default) construtor to instantiate an object and set its fields via reflection. Can you describe what you are expecting?

Comment: Well I need to set the `LocalizedString` in the `Device` and since it is not being set in the adapter then my question is: Do you know how to set it without using the adapter? Basically I need to do `new LocalizedString(en, fi)`

Comment: write a getter inside Device like->   public LocalizedString getLocalizedStrings() {
        return new LocalizedString(en, fi);
    }

Comment: Not sure if that is the best practise but is seems to work. Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the source of the JSON, then a modification of that JSON structure is easy to solve your problem.

If you can not, the one way we can use to solve your problem is to use Jackson and custom deserializer:

```
public class DeviceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Device> { 

    public DeviceDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public DeviceDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public Device deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String id = getStringValue(node, "id");
        String en = getStringValue(node, "name.en_EN");
        String fi = getStringValue(node, "name.fi_FI");
        LocalizedString localized = new LocalizedString(en, fi);
        return new Device(id, localizedString);
    }

    private String getStringValue(JsonNode node, String key) {
        // Throws exception or use null is up to you to decide
        return Optional.ofNullable(node.get("id"))
                       .map(JsonNode::asText)
                       .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Manually register the deserializer yourself or using the annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DeviceDeserializer.class)
public class Device {
...
```

Note that you must enable retrofit jackson converter plugin: (see the [Retrofit Configuration](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) part)

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in the getStringValue `.map(Node::asText)`.. it does not seem to understand what the `asText` does there.

Comment: @kataroty change it to JsonNode::asText

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Get nested JSON object with GSON using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit?rq=1)