# Retrieve specific field in JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have a data class which represents the object I'm receiving from my API :

```java
data class MyObject(
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int,
    @SerializedName("status.description") var status: String
)
```

This is what my JSON looks like :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "status": {
        "description": "OK"
    }
}
```

I'm fetching these data with Retrofit using `Gson` adapter but I always have my status attribute to **null**. Even if I use `Moshi` it's still **null**.

How can I get this attribute from my JSON without having to create a class `Status` with only one and a unique attribute named description?

Comment: There is a cool lib for json processing out there, tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-json-klaxson#json-path-query-api

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
data class MyObject(
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int,
    @SerializedName("status") var status: Status
)

data class Status(
    @SerializedName("description") var description: String,
)
```

if you don't want above method :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23071080/10182897

Comment: In addition to this correct answer, you can omit using @SerializedName annotation if the field has the same name as Json field

Answer (score 0):

```
data class MyObject(
    val id: Int,
    val status: Status
)

data class Status(
    val description: String
)
```

You can use `val` to make thiese fields final. Also one trick to keep in mind, if you use final fields, kotlin is able to make a smartcast for you.

Example:

```
data class Status(
    val description: String?
)

val status: Status = Status("success")
if ( status.description != null){
  // status.description will be smartcasted to String, not String?
}
```