# Parse JSON Object inside JSON Object

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

I want to parse Json object using Retrofit. What is the best way to parse "Phone" and "Address"?
Thank you.

```
{
    "name": "Miss Piggy",
    "id": "13",
    "companyName": "Muppets, Baby",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "smallImageURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/technical-challenge/v3/images/miss-piggy-small.jpg",
    "largeImageURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/technical-challenge/v3/images/miss-piggy-large.jpg",
    "emailAddress": "Miss.Piggy@muppetsbaby.com",
    "birthdate": "1987-05-11",
    "phone": {
        "work": "602-225-9543",
        "home": "602-225-9188",
        "mobile": ""
    },
    "address": {
        "street": "3530 E Washington St",
        "city": "Phoenix",
        "state": "AZ",
        "country": "US",
        "zipCode": "85034"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get nested JSON object with GSON using retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JSON parsing library (such as [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)) with the correct [retrofit converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters) in order to create classes (data classes in kotlin) for parsing the embed objects.

An example in kotlin.

Response class

```
data class Response (
    val name: String,
    val id: String,
    val companyName: String,
    val isFavorite: Boolean,
    val smallImageURL: String,
    val largeImageURL: String,
    val emailAddress: String,
    val birthdate: String,
    val phone: Phone,
    val address: Address)
```

Address Class

```
data class Address (
    val street: String,
    val city: String,
    val state: String,
    val country: String,
    val zipCode: String )
```

Phone Class

```
data class Phone (
    val work: String,
    val home: String,
    val mobile: String)
```

For more details take a look in [Google's Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-internet-data) example

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to get the value of any string from any sub JSON object then using Android JAVA's built-in JSON parsers can help you without any new library.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
// extract phone object
JSONObject phoneJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("phone");
// we can any data of the sub json object of main object
// get string value of work
String valueOfWork = phoneJsonObject.getString("work");

// extract address object
JSONObject addressJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("address");
// we can any data of the sub json object of main object
// get string value of street
String valueOfStreet = phoneJsonObject.getString("street");

Log.i("Getting Value of Work from Phone Object", valueOfWork);
Log.i("Getting Value of Street from Address Object", valueOfStreet);
```